# SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) "View Dependencies" not displaying correctly

Tags: sql-server, ssms

[image: "View dependencies" text is cut off]

I just got a new computer at work. Switched from window 10 home to pro, and when I installed SSMS on the new PC the view dependencies windows is not displaying at correct size. The 'Object Dependencies' Window is not listed in the adjustable Fonts and Colors settings. Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/39218473-ssms-view-dependencies-dialog-not-opimized-for)
Just [override the DPI Scaling in App properties](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2017/05/19/improving-high-dpi-experience-gdi-based-desktop-apps/) to fix.

Comment: what do you mean by override the dpi scaling. how did you fix it?